# How bind to TemplatedParent from DataTemplate defined in a style?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles, custom-controls, silverlight-5.0

I am developing a custom control derived from an `ItemsControl`. In the generic.xaml-file I created the style for that control and also defined an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Red">
                    <!-- Other things in here -->
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to bind the `Background` property of the `Border` in the `DataTemplate` to a dependency property of the `MyItemsControl`.

If found several questions here suggesting to use the element name of the `MyItemsControl` in the binding, but that only works when defining the `ItemTemplate` where the control is being used. I also tried binding to a `RelativeSource` defining the `local:MyItemsControl` as ancestor type.

Nothing worked. What am I missing here?

Comment: In a `ControlTemplate` you could use TemplateBinding. But this is only available in `ControlTemplate`s... I would try the ancestor way.

Comment: I tried that - but couldn't get it to work. So either this doesn't work - or I made a mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What`s the type of that DependencyProperty? Is it `Brush` or `string`? 
This simple code works for me:

```
Background="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

Just for test here I bind to Name property of ItemsControl that is 'Yellow' - and it works.